# How to create a website with ironpython

Tags: ironpython

I see that it is a lot of difficulty creating a website with ironpython with dyjango. Is there any alternative or webframework for ironpython?

Answer (score 0):

You could use IronPython with ASP.NET or even with ASP.NET MVC :-) There is an [example on codeplex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/17613). Unfortunately IronPython is not mature enough yet and the road could be bumpy.

Comment: It's not that IronPython isn't mature - there just hasn't been anyone to focus on the web stories, so those are lacking.